# Can I set the dependency version of one of my dependencies in npm?

Tags: npm

I'm guessing that a recent update in jsdom broke the juice library.

Can I specify in my project which version of jsdom should the juice library use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can lock down dependency versions using [npm shrinkwrap](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-shrinkwrap.html). This will generate an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file respected by `npm install` that allows you to explicitly specify the dependency versions you desire.

From the documentation:

```
{
  "name": "A",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "B": {
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "dependencies": {
        "C": {
          "version": "0.1.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```